# BASH, passing variables to a string for sqlite

Tags: bash, sqlite

Ive hit a dead end trying to pass variables created in bash to a sqlite command string.Below you can see I am trying to write the artist_id (foreign key) into the songs table in artist_id. I can retrieve th artist_id field fine from the artists table. When I try to create a new record in the songs table with the variable $artist_id, I get an error;

> Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Its definitely the correct key, 4 in this case, but sqlite doesn't seem to be accepting it so I think it may be a formatting issue? I tried removing quotes, adding '..etc. but no joy, any ideas?

```
artistcheck=$(sqlite3 "$dbFile" "$forkey SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM artists WHERE artist_name='${ARRAY[2]}' LIMIT 1);")
if [ "$artistcheck" -eq 1 ]; then
    artistid=$(sqlite3 "$dbFile" "$forkey SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist_name='${ARRAY[2]}';")
  echo "Yep, "${ARRAY[2]}" exists and the id is $artistid."
else
    echo "Nope, "${ARRAY[2]}" doesnt exist"
    sqlite3 "$dbFile" "$forkey INSERT INTO artists (artist_name) VALUES ('${ARRAY[2]}');"
    artistid=$(sqlite3 "$dbFile" "$forkey SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist_name='${ARRAY[2]}';")
    echo "New Artist created. Name: ${ARRAY[2]} and ID is $artistid."
fi

songcheck=$(sqlite3 "$dbFile" "$forkey SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM songs WHERE song_name='${ARRAY[1]}' AND artist_id='$artistid' LIMIT 1);")
if [ "$songcheck" -eq 1 ]; then
    songid=$(sqlite3 "$dbFile" "$forkey SELECT song_id FROM songs WHERE song_name='${ARRAY[1]}' AND artist_id='$artistid';")
  echo "Yep, "${ARRAY[1]}" exists and the song ID is $songid and the artist id is $artistid."
else
  echo "Nope, "${ARRAY[1]}" doesnt exist"
  sqlite3 "$dbFile" "$forkey INSERT INTO songs (artist_id, song_name) VALUES ('$artist_id','${ARRAY[2]}');"
  songid=$(sqlite3 "$dbFile" "$forkey SELECT song_id FROM songs WHERE song_name='${ARRAY[1]}' AND artist_id='$artist_id';")
  echo "New Song created. Name: ${ARRAY[1]} and song ID is $songid and the artist id is $artistid."
fi
```

Comment: Which line specifically is generating that error? What is `$forkey`? What constraints do you have on the tables here?

Comment: Also, what, if any, environment variables are you defining for use in this code segment?

Comment: I just realised as soon as you asked about environment variables that I had mixed up artist_id with $artistid face palm! Well, that explains it! Sometimes it's good to get a fresh pair of eyes on it! $forkey is to set foreign_keys constraint, so I don't forget! Any advice dealing with SQLite with bash? Seems long-winded!

Comment: You might want to write up an answer if the problem is solved. "Any advice dealing with SQLite with bash?" Same as dealing with everything else, in every language: use meaningful, memorable variable names, and be consistent with naming conventions. In particular, uppercase variable names are usually reserved for environment variables and you'd better not use them for regular variables.

Comment: Good advice indeed! I was just trying to get to grips with the sql syntax, in the process I was lazy with my naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixed up the variable $artistid with the field 'artist_id' in the sql statement. 4th line from the bottom I believe. Moral: use meaningful variable names and lay off the caffeine.